# Cannot Locate Query Referenced In Another Query

Tags: ms-access

I went to fix an Overflow error we had in an Access Database created by someone who has left the company. I have the error fixed, but something puzzled me as I was researching the error.

The error was in a report that references a query that does not exist in the database, however the report runs perfectly fine once the data was cleared up (the error that got fixed). The query is referenced by name, such as qryQUERYNAME, but I can't find it anywhere.

Any suggestions on where it may be hiding?

Comment: Exactly what have you attempted to find it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038187/where-can-a-query-be-found-in-a-microsoft-access-database-besides-queries

Comment: Hidden objects strike again! I don't deal in Access/VBA so I keep forgetting about hidden objects.

This is why I program in other languages and just use Access for info storage.

Thanks.

Comment: Most likely the previous programmer marked the query as hidden for a reason; you don't do that for fun. With no documentation left, it is your task to figure out why.

Comment: Did you check if it is simply hidden in the querydefs list? I found this link which could help in showing it up [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/25d9dafd-b446-40ba-8dbd-a0efa983f2ff/how-to-programatically-hide-a-querydef)